# How to complete a rolling 12 month

Tags: visual-studio

I am using the expression below in Visual studio to complete a table so it shows the next six months worth of data. Problem I have now is that it is going into the next year, and i am getting an error on my report. Can someone please help:

Currently i am using the code below.

```
=MONTHNAME(IIF(MONTH(Today)+6>12,MONTH(Today)+4-12,MONTH(Today)+6), TRUE) & " " &
IIF(MONTH(Today)+6>12,YEAR(NOW)+1,YEAR(NOW))
```

Ideally i want it to go into the next year. Example is Jan 2020

Comment: What does the error message say?

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out as soon as I posted this pretty much.
=MONTHNAME(IIF(MONTH(Today)+6>12,MONTH(Today)+6-12,MONTH(Today)+6), TRUE) & " " &
IIF(MONTH(Today)+6>12,YEAR(NOW)+1,YEAR(NOW))